# More Route disfunction in React 16

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

G'day

Following the tutorials in the older versions of React I have this in
my routes

```
<Route path="/people"                   component={People}                          />
<Route path="/people_new"               component={CreatePeople}                    />
<Route path="/people/:email"            component={ShowPeople}                      />
<Route path="/people_edit/:email"       component={EditPeople}                      />
```

I have been implementing an upgrade to 16.  The ShowPeople is not being called.  Is this a change in the routing?

More code
people.js

```
import React, { Component }     from 'react';
import { connect }              from 'react-redux';
import { Link }                 from 'react-router-dom';

import { apiGetData }           from '../actions/api';      // our home spun API
import { FETCH_PEOPLE }         from '../actions/api';     

const API_KEY = '';                                         // not needed at the moment.  reminder.
const URL     = 'people';


//----------------------------
class People extends Component {

    //--------------------
    componentWillMount() {
        const url = `${URL}${API_KEY}`;                 // target URI will fetch ALL entries

        console.log('In people.js  URL ==  ');
        console.log(url);
        this.props.apiGetData(FETCH_PEOPLE, url);       // call the API
    }


    //-------------
    renderPeople() {

        console.log('In renderPeople :', this.props.people);
        return this.props.people.map((person) => {
            return(
                <li className="list-group-item" key={person.id}>
                    <Link to={"/people/" + person.email}>
                        <strong>{person.name}</strong>
                        <span className="pull-right">{person.surname}</span>
                    </Link>
                </li>
            );
        });
    }

    //--------
    render() {
        console.log('made it into People');
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="jumbotron">
                    <h2>Asset-IQ - Live Build - May 2017</h2>
                    <h2>List of People</h2> 
                </div>
                <div className="text-right">
                    <Link to="/people_new" className="btn btn-primary">
                        New Person
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul className="list-group">
                        {this.renderPeople()}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

//-------------------------------
function mapStateToProps(state) {

    return { people: state.people.all };
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {apiGetData: apiGetData })(People);

//---------------------   EOF ---------------------------------------------
```

I was running a VERY early versionof React that came with a boilerplate
I got from a Udemy course.  I didn't realise until a few weeks ago I was
running 0.9x!

The app is only half written so now is a good time to join this century.
Here is the component that USED to be rendered

```
// vim: set expandtab tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 autoindent:

import React, { Component }         from 'react';
import { connect }                  from 'react-redux';
import { Link }                     from 'react-router-dom';

import { apiGetData }               from '../actions/api';
import { apiDeleteData }            from '../actions/api';
import { FETCH_PERSON }             from '../actions/api';
import { DELETE_PERSON }            from '../actions/api';

//--------------------------------
class ShowPeople extends Component {

    //--------------------
    componentDidMount() {
        const target = `people/${this.props.match.params.email}`;       // email is the id passed in as a prop
        console.log(target);                                            // quick look at the value
        this.props.apiGetData(FETCH_PERSON, target);                    // get the record from Python
    }

    //---------------
    onDeleteClick() {
        const target = `${this.props.match.params.email}`;

        let ok = confirm("Sure you want to ZAP this mofo?");

        if (ok) {
            this.props.apiDeleteData(DELETE_PERSON, target).then(() =>
                alert("They gone...."));
        }
        //browserHistory.push('/people');  HOW do we do this in React 16

    }


    //--------
    render() {
        const { person } = this.props;
        console.log("In person");
        console.log(person);
        if (!person) {
            return (
                <div>
                    SPINNER....
                </div>
            );
        }

        //------
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="jumbotron">
                    <h2>Asset-IQ - Live Build - May 2017</h2>
                    <h2>Person Detail</h2> 
                </div>
                <h2>{person.name} {person.surname}</h2>
                <Link to="/people" className="btn btn-primary">Back</Link>
                <button className="btn btn-warning pull-right" onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind(this)}>
                    Delete
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

//--------------------------------
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { person: state.people.person };
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { apiGetData, apiDeleteData })(ShowPeople);

//---------------------   EOF ---------------------------------------------------
```

Cheers

Comment: Which version of react-router are you using?

Comment: react-router-dom ^4.2.2

Comment: react-router v4 is compatible with react 16... how are you writing your url? Can you show the component where you're rendering your routes and the `ShowPeople` component that's not rendering?

Comment: Up in the original post!

Comment: It seems ok, what happens when you click the Link to `/people/someemail`?

Comment: The URL in the browser changes to
http://localhost:8888/people/donald@duck.com
The screen doesn't change.  I still have the list of users.
If you hit refresh with this in the URL I get
Cannot GET /people/donald@duck.com

If I change the route to
/people_show/:email
it works.  I wondered if the path re-use might be verboten in v4.x but I can't see it mentioned anywhere.

Comment: If your `Route`s are inside a `Switch` component then only the first match will render, in that case you have to add `exact`. If not, every matched Route renders. The Cannot GET is another (common) problem, for which you can find plenty of answers

Comment: Cheers mate! That got it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `exact` attribute in your routes to make it work correctly.

```
<Route path="/people" exact             component={People}                          />
<Route path="/people_new"               component={CreatePeople}                    />
<Route path="/people/:email"            component={ShowPeople}                      />
<Route path="/people_edit/:email"       component={EditPeople}
```

[Here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool) you have more detailed information about this attribute.

And [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rj4mjk3jpm) you have a live demo.

Comment: Spot on.  Thanks man!  That was my LAST swap to 16 bug.  I hope!  Where has the "This is the ANSWER" checkbox gone?

Comment: I won't want to be killjoy but if the course has a testing section well ... hahah. To mark the answer as correct you can [check this out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)